# Creating multiple sub accounts in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a parent Azure account and I have multiple resources in it. Now, I want to have multiple child accounts in such a way that I don't want the azure child account to see the resources in azure parent account and other child accounts and vice versa.

How can I implement this in Azure and what are the APIs supported for this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show screenshots about the parent account and child account you created, thanks

Comment: I haven't created child account. I want to create it. You can relate this to following AWS structure. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html

Comment: As I know, in the Azure, you could sign up by using the personal account and school or work account. For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/sign-up-organization).

Comment: In other words, I want to know if we can link one subscription to other subscription where former is the master and later is sub- subscription. Can we do that in azure?

Comment: If you want to know about subscription, you could directly request support in the Azure portal. For the details, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like AWS IAM accounts?

I'm not very expert about Azure, but I found this link that could be helpful.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/product-categories/identity/

Apparently, there are some different services that you can use to divide your resources.